# installing kivy on a Raspberry Pi with python 3.2

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, kivy

I am looking for an installation procedure for kivy on an Raspberry Pi with Python 3.

UPDATED

My procedure so far is:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3 python3-pip python3-numpy pkg-config libgl1-mesa-dev libgles2-mesa-dev git-core libgstreamer1.0-dev gstreamer1.0-plugins-{bad,base,good,ugly} gstreamer1.0-{omx,alsa} libsdl-dev libsdl-image1.2-dev libsdl-mixer1.2-dev libsdl-ttf2.0-dev libsmpeg-dev libportmidi-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev freetds-dev

sudo apt-get remove task-desktop wolfram-engine 

sudo pip-3.2 -v install pysdl2 --upgrade
sudo pip-3.2 -v install pymssql --upgrade
sudo pip-3.2 -v install pygame --upgrade
sudo pip-3.2 -v install cython --upgrade
sudo pip-3.2 -v install kivy --upgrade
```

Don't worry about some problems when installing cython. If the gcc compiler reports an error, just restart it. Sometimes the memory is not enough. That is why I uninstalled the desktop and wolfram.

The error now occurs when starting kivy with:

```
python3
import kivy.app
```

The listing is:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ python3
Python 3.2.3 (default, Mar  1 2013, 11:53:50) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import kivy.app
[INFO   ] Kivy v1.8.0
[WARNING] [Config      ] Older configuration version detected (0 instead of 10)
[WARNING] [Config      ] Upgrading configuration in progress.
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/pi/.kivy/logs/kivy_14-06-21_0.txt
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 157 symbols loaded
[DEBUG  ] [Cache       ] register <kv.lang> with limit=None, timeout=Nones
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/kivy/app.py", line 321, in <module>
     from kivy.base import runTouchApp, stopTouchApp
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/kivy/base.py", line 30, in <module>
     from kivy.lang import Builder
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 1814, in <module>
     Builder.load_file(join(kivy_data_dir, 'style.kv'), rulesonly=True)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 1444, in load_file
     return self.load_string(data, **kwargs)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 1491, in load_string
     parser = Parser(content=string, filename=fn)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 1049, in __init__
     self.parse(content)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 1126, in parse
     rule.precompile()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 917, in precompile
     x.precompile()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 917, in precompile
     x.precompile()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 913, in precompile
     x.precompile()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 843, in precompile
     self.co_value = compile(value, self.ctx.filename or '<string>', mode)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/kivy/data/style.kv", line 715
     u'{0}\n[size=13sp][color=999999]{1}[/color][/size]'.format(root.title or '', root.desc or '')
                                                       ^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "freezes"?

Comment: it seems that the cython installation via pip took a big amount of time. There are no outputs that the build process is still running.

Actucal I have an error when the "Cython.Compiler.code" extension is build.

I'll keep the question up to date

Comment: It can take a long time to build Cython on a regular computer. It is possible that it could take up to an hour on RPi. If the build has not actually crashed, let it keep going.

Comment: @brousch your are absolutly right. It took a long time and sometimes breaks. By restarting the process it is possible to finish the process. I updated the question and added that information to it.

Comment: So what's the question here ?

Comment: @andré-daniel The question is to setup python3 + kivy on a RPi proper. Actual I am stuck at a error produced by importing the app modul of kivy.

Comment: there is a problem with cython
actual I am trying to get cython and kivy with the pip script to run proper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On GitHub I got the information that kivy only supports python3 from version 3.3. Seems we have to wait till python 3.3 or 3.4 get avaible for RPi.