# Proper way of installation of Kivy 1.10+ with Python 3 on Raspberry Pi 3 with 7" Touchscreen Display

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, raspberry-pi3

I'm searching around for quite a long time for a description of a proper way of installation of Kivy 1.10.0 on a Raspberry Pi 3 with Raspbian Stretch Lite and an attached 7" Raspberry Pi 3 Touch Display. My problem is that there is a description on the [Kivy Site](https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-rpi.html) for Python 2.7 but there is no update on this page for the Python 3 way.
In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25505661/installing-kivy-on-a-raspberry-pi-with-python-3-2) thread a way is shown for Python 3.2 but it seems to be not complete. On [this](https://github.com/mrichardson23/rpi-kivy-screen/blob/master/README.md) page the way is also shown for 2.7 only. I know that there is a [distribution](http://kivypie.mitako.eu) that sums all up but I want to install it on an origin Raspbian.

Cut a long story short: Where can I find a complete list of all dependencies and requirements for a working Kivy application on a RPi3 + 7" Touch?

Thanks a lot for your support in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed the steps decribed [here](https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-rpi.html) for "Manual installation (On Raspbian Jessie)" from kivy itself, which you already linked. Replace `pip` with `pip3`. If I remember correctly, that's all I did.

Also, first try to upgrade Cython without a specific version, as it might be that it will install a higher version.

(It takes a long time, prepare yourself to wait for a while...)

See comments for fix to another problem

Comment: If I follow the manual installation and try to start a kivy application the app got stuck:

`[INFO   ] Kivy: v1.10.0
[INFO   ] Python: v3.5.3 (default, Jan 19 2017, 14:11:04) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170124]
[INFO   ] Window: Provider: egl_rpi
[INFO   ] Window: Provider: sdl2(['window_egl_rpi'] ignored)
[CRITICAL] Window: Unable to find any valuable Window provider.
egl_rpi - EGLError: EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED (code x3001)
sdl2 - RuntimeError: b'No available video device`

Comment: Problem solved: As mentioned [here](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/5360) there is an issue with Stretch and the actual stable version of kivy. But `pip3 install --upgrade --force-reinstall git+https://github.com/kivy/kivy.git@master` did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Came across the solution for installing kivy on Raspberry Pi 3+ here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kivy-users/OSpnIv4a_S4

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install libsdl2-dev libsdl2-image-dev libsdl2-mixer-dev libsdl2-ttf-dev \
 pkg-config libgl1-mesa-dev libgles2-mesa-dev \
 python-setuptools libgstreamer1.0-dev git-core \
 gstreamer1.0-plugins-{bad,base,good,ugly} \
 gstreamer1.0-{omx,alsa} python-dev
(Note that I stripped off the "cython" from the above command)
sudo pip install cython==0.20.1
sudo pip install git+https://github.com/kivy/kivy.git@7e789b2
```

Worked perfectly for me after struggling with dependencies for a couple of days of try and fail.